# Swift: Hacer que la altura de un Label crezca según contenido

Tags: swift, label, height

Tengo algo parecido a un chat en donde tengo un `scrollView` y dentro un `stackView` en donde muestro los mensajes, el problema: la altura de los label no se ajusta al contenido del mensaje, he intentado varios ajustes y ninguno me ha servido:

Lo que hago: poner un `UIView` principal (rojo) para que este se expanda en todo el `stackView` (morado) después de esto pongo toda la burbuja que representa el mensaje con todos sus elementos internos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se muestra la pantalla de dos dimensiones diferentes donde se aprecia que uno muestra mas texto que otro, incluso curiosamente hay algo de `overflow`de la burbuja sobre el `View`(rojo) o sobre el elemento del `stack`

El codigo:

La burbuja tiene su propia clase donde solo se gestionan sus elementos internos:

```
class BubbleMessage: UIView {
    
    lazy var text: UILabel = {
        let text = UILabel()
        text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        text.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        text.numberOfLines = 0
        text.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        return text
    }()
    
    lazy var lblCreationDate: UILabel = {
        let date = UILabel()
        date.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        date.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return date
    }()
    
    lazy var lblUser: UILabel = {
        let user = UILabel()
        user.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        user.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
        return user
    }()

    lazy var imgCheck: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "checkmark"))
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private func setupView(message: String, creationDate: String, online: Bool, userName: String?) {
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false        
        text.text = message
        addSubview(text)
        lblCreationDate.text = creationDate
        addSubview(lblCreationDate)
        imgCheck.isHidden = !online
        addSubview(imgCheck)
        
        text.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 3).isActive = true
        text.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.bounds.width
        text.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        text.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        //let size = heightForView(text: message, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18), width: self.frame.width)
        //print("s:\(size)")
        //text.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size).isActive = true
        
        lblCreationDate.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -3).isActive = true
        lblCreationDate.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgCheck.leftAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        lblCreationDate.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: text.bottomAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
        imgCheck.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -3).isActive = true
        imgCheck.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        imgCheck.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
        imgCheck.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
    }
    func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = text

        label.sizeToFit()
        return ceil(label.frame.height)
    }
}
```

La funcion `heightForView`fue una de las formas que encontre para determinar la altura de un label pero no me funciono.

La propiedad `text.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.bounds.width` también la mencionan el otro post que la verdad no entendí muy bien su uso y al intentar aplicarla tampoco me hizo diferencia.

Ahora esta es la parte de código que crea los objetos burbuja y las añade al `stack`

```
func createMessageInterface(message: String, position: Position, creationDate: String, online: Bool, userName: String?){
        let bFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 20)
        let bubble = BubbleMessage(frame: bFrame, message: message, creationDate: creationDate, online: online, userName: userName)
        lazy var canva: UIView = {
            let canva = UIView()
            canva.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            canva.addSubview(bubble)
            canva.backgroundColor = .red
            return canva
        }()
        stackMessage.addArrangedSubview(canva)
        stackMessage.backgroundColor = .purple
        switch position{
            case .left:
                bubble.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canva.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
                bubble.backgroundColor = color.gray75
                bubble.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
                bubble.imgCheck.isHidden = true
            case .right:
                bubble.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canva.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        }
        canva.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackMessage.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        canva .rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackMessage.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: bubble, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: canva, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.2, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: bubble, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: canva, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.85, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: canva, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: bubble.text, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.7, constant: 20).isActive = true
        
        bubble.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canva.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

Canva es el `View` rojo que ocupa todo el `stack` que uso para poner libremente la burbuja a la izquierda o derecha según el caso.

Lo que he intentado hasta aquí es, tratar de que el `View` rojo este 1.7 veces mas alto(height) que el `Label` del texto:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: canva, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: bubble.text, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.7, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

En la clase de la burbuja hay una linea comentada:

```
text.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

para poner directamente la altura al label del texto y es lo único que ha funcionado pero evidentemente no todos los textos son iguales, necesito alturas variantes.

y esta otra forma con la función anteriormente mencionado, por algun motivo solo me acomoda el ultimo elemento:

```
let size = heightForView(text: message, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18), width: self.frame.width)
text.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size).isActive = true
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que tantas cosas estoy haciendo mal o no estoy haciendo?

Answer (score 1):

Me perdí un poco con el código pero vi que hay un constraint `bottomAnchor` para ajustarse con la parte inferior.

En este ejemplo tengo un contenedor y dentro de este un label que va a cambiar de texto cada par de segundos para visualizar como se ajusta al tamaño del texto.

1. Creamos el contenedor y el label.

   ```
   let containerView: UIView = {
       let view = UIView()
       view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
       view.backgroundColor = .gray
       return view
   }()

   let labelView: UILabel = {
       let label = UILabel()
       label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       label.numberOfLines = 0
       label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
       return label
   }()
   ```
2. Agrego los constraint y el `bottomAnchor` le agrego al label y no al contenedor.

   ```
   func setupConstraints() {
       self.containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
       self.containerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
       self.containerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true

       self.labelView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
       self.labelView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.rightAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
       self.labelView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
       self.labelView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
   }
   ```
3. Agrego el contenedor, el label, llamo a la función para los constraint y agrego un texto extenso por defecto. De manera asíncrona se cambian esos textos para visualizar el cambio de tamaño.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       //Texto por defecto
       self.labelView.text = "In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available."
       //Agrego el label al contenedor
       self.containerView.addSubview(self.labelView)
       //Agrego el contenedor a la vista
       self.view.addSubview(self.containerView)
       //Configuro los constraints
       setupConstraints()
       //Después de 4 segundo se cambia de texto
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
           self.labelView.text = "Hola soy un nuevo texto"
       }
       //Después de 8 segundo se cambia de texto nuevamente
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 8) {
           self.labelView.text = "Este texto es un poco extenso y se va a expandir después de contraerse con el anterior mensaje"
       }
   }
   ```

El resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso el contenedor que tiene el label no debería tener `bottomAnchor` y de igual manera el contenedor rojo.

Comment: Según yo hice lo mismo, solo que como debajo del ```Label``` tengo otros elementos anclo el label a ese otro elemento y ese a la parte inferior del ```View```

Comment: ```text.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 3).isActive = true``` 
```text.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true```
```text.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true``` 

```lblCreationDate.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: text.bottomAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true``` 
```lblCreationDate.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -3).isActive = true```

Comment: Solo por curiosidad agregue el bottom también al bottom del contenedor directamente y el resultado es el mismo, solo que ahora se sobreponen los otros elementos inferiores.
```text.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -3).isActive = true```

 No se si tenga algo que ver el ```stack```

Comment: Lo mejor sería ir haciendo pruebas con un contenedor, después con el stack y ver cuál constraint no funciona bien.